# Angular Service DB call persist Data

Tags: angularjs

This is kind of a general question regarding Angular Services.
I have a Service. Inside this service we do a Db call to grab a bunch of data. Lets say it takes 3 seconds for example to return on all the data. The start of the DB call/function inside the service will begin once a controller with the injected Service starts loading. After 3 seconds, i get the Data from the service/query. Lets say, I want to use this same service for the DB call, exact same query, for another page/controller. Is it going to have to run the same query again? Or will the data from the 1st time the query was ran from the first controller/page still persist the same data, negating the query from running?

Essentially, I don't want to have to call the DB again, only to return the exact same data I got from the first time the Query was called. I want to be able to just call the query/DB once, and use that data in two different controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call from the service will take place if you move to the other controller and call the function again.

In order to use the data from the first call in the other controller you can use the either of following ways:

1) Store data in $sessionStorage or $localStorage

2) Use $broadcast, $emit and $on events to share data(depending on how your controllers are called)*